# How does clan ranking work in Call of Duty Elite, and how can I increase it?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3, call-of-duty-elite

In Call Of Duty Elite (Modern Warfare 3, PS3) I cannot figure out how to increase my clan ranking. I effectively added 9 friends to my clan, but the ranking is still at 1.

How does clan ranking work, and how can I increase it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently there are very few ways of increasing your clan rank.  Clan rank goes up by accumulating clan XP.

You can get clan XP by adding people to your clan who have "Founder Status" - this means people who joined the for-pay version of Elite right around the Modern Warfare 3 launch.  Since most of these people are in clans already, and it's a one-time bonus, this is not really a good source of clan XP.

The "real" way of getting clan XP is participating in Clan Operations:

> Clan operations award clans that finish in the bronze tier or higher. Bronze requirements may change from op to op, but generally if your clan finishes in the upper half of an operation, it will be rewarded.
>
> These rewards include badges that are displayed in your clan’s showcase and Clan XP.

Only the clan leader can enroll in Clan Ops, and in order to get badges or XP, you're going to have to have your clan members play the designated game type during the operations period.  There's more detail on the "[Compete](https://elite.callofduty.com/compete)" tab of Elite, under the heading "What are Clan Operations," which is just above the photos of upcoming Clan Ops.

The MW3 events team has had a spotty track record with scheduling and awarding Clan Ops to date, so if clan ranking/XP is important to you, you'll want to check in early and often for new ops.

Answer (score 0):

Clan Ops have changed significantly in two ways.

1. They happen much more frequently (though often without enough notice for my liking).  The best way to know they are coming is to follow [Beachead Studios on twitter](http://twitter.com/#!/beachheadstudio).  Or you can just lurk on the Elite service itself (Compete tab).
2. **100% of clans** that score at least 1 point in a given game type [now get a bronze badge](http://forums.activision.com/message/205549272).  This means that it is in your best interest as a Clan leader to enroll in everything (refer to my previous comment).  At bronze rates (250 xp per event), it will take a LONG time to get to the high tiers, but you can get past the first few levels relatively easily, netting among other things a custom clan title.  Check out all the rewards [here](http://www.mw3-forum.com/forum/showthread.php?t=3333).